# How do I allow SSH access to a range of IP's in AWS ec2 Security groups

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, subnet

I want to allow access from 181.49.80.0 to 181.49.100.255 But amn't usre how to do this using CDIR notation.

(without explicitly allowing 181.49.80.0/24, 181.49.81.0/24 etc...)

Many thanks,

Danny.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools online such as [this one](http://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr#range) that will help you with this. When I input your IP range into that tool I get the following 3 CIDR groups

```
181.49.80.0/20
181.49.96.0/22
181.49.100.0/24
```

So you would need to add three rules to the Security Group to effectively allow access to that entire IP range.